# how to do an Eloquent request so that the date field matches the values of my array passed with ajax in the where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have an array of three date values ​​and i would like to make an eloquent request for laravel so that my created_at field could match any of the values ​​in my array
My table has the following three values passed with ajax: today's date, the date of 7 days before and the date of 30 days before. I want to retrieve today's offers, from 7 days before and 30 days before depending on the 3 checkbox check.
here is a request that I made but it does not find any offer in my database and it is normal.

```
if (isset($request->finalDate)) {
        $finalDate = $request->finalDate;
        $filtreDate = Job::with(['Category', 'Ville', 'Type', 'Salaire', 'User', 'Entreprise', 'Level'])
            ->where('created_at', '=', explode(',', $finalDate))
            ->where('confirmed', 1)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
        response()->json($filtreDate);
```

here is some of my javascript code switch to ajax

```
 var date = [];
       $(".filtreDate").each(function () {
           if($(this).is(":checked")) {
               date.push($(this).val());
           }
       });
       finalDate = date.toString();
       console.log(finalDate);
```

Comment: In order to improve my sample code in the answer below, I would like to know the format of `$finalDate` / how the 3 checkbox get received server side.

Comment: I see the updated javascript code, could you share some dummy contents of your console.log?

Comment: hi @Quezler I added a part of my javascript code

Comment: when I check my 3 checboxes here is the result of console.log 2018-05-03 23:09:45,2018-04-26 23:09:45,2018-04-03 23:09:45 and my field created_at has the same format

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input received from the frontend, i have updated my answer;

This might not work out of the box, but should point you in a correct-ish direction:

```
$dates = explode(',', $finalDate);

$query = Job::with(['Category', 'Ville', 'Type', 'Salaire', 'User', 'Entreprise', 'Level'])
    ->where('confirmed', 1)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');


$query = $query->whereDate('created_at', array_shift($dates));

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $query = $query->orWhereDate('created_at', $date);
}

$results = $query->->paginate(5);
```

Comment: With this new code I have this error:(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method whereDate does not exist. 
I work on laravel 5.4 i do not understand why.

Comment: What if you move `->paginate(5)` to the bottom line of the example?

Comment: when i move paginate(5) i have this error: (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereDate(), 1 passed in C:\wamp64\www\237jobs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1254 and at least 2 expected

Comment: There is a bug in `orWhereDate()`, you have to use `$q->orWhereDate('created_at', '=', $date);` instead. The bug was fixed in 5.6.

Comment: I had some errors and I modified the following lines   $q->whereDate('created_at','>=', array_shift($dateArray));
                    foreach ($dateArray as $date) {
                        $q->orWhereDate('created_at', '>=', $date);
                    } it works very well. thank you very much @quelzer

Comment: @hashcode be careful with `>=` in your current context, it means any post that it jounger than that date, instead of exactly 0, 7 or 30 days!

Comment: @Quezler that's exactly the behavior I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use closuer function for `created_at`

```
$finalDate = $request->finalDate;
$dateArray = explode(',', $finalDate);
$query = Job::with(['Category', 'Ville', 'Type', 'Salaire', 'User', 'Entreprise', 'Level'])
                ->where('confirmed', 1);
if ($dateArray) {
     $query->where(function($q) use($dateArray) {
        $q->whereDate('created_at','=',array_shift($dateArray));
                foreach ($dateArray as $date) {
                    $q->orWhereDate('created_at', '=', $date);
                }
            });
        }
$filtreDate = $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(5);
```

Note : `whereDate` introduced in Laravel 5.3

Comment: I tried your code but I have this error in the console: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWhereDate(), 2 passed in C:\wamp64\www\237jobs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1254 and exactly 3 expected

Comment: This is a bug in `orWhereDate()`, use `$q->orWhereDate('created_at', 
 '=', $date);` instead. The bug was fixed in 5.6.

Comment: I had some errors and I modified the following lines   $q->whereDate('created_at','>=', array_shift($dateArray));
                    foreach ($dateArray as $date) {
                        $q->orWhereDate('created_at', '>=', $date);
                    } it works very well. thank you very much @Jonas